# vs code show double suggestion

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, autosuggest, pylance

[Sample 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXnXC.png)

[Sample 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38ngy.png)

VS Code intellisense shows double suggestions in python whenever I write.

Is there a setting in VS Code, so I can change them to the normal state?

Answer (score 0):

Press **Ctrl+Shift+X** to see if other prompt extensions are installed and python original completion is applied at the same time.

Disable unwanted prompt extensions can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/11938). Upgrading the **Jupyter** extension to the pre-release version solved it.

[image]