# Duplicate problems in VS Code with Pylance

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pylance

I am using Python 3.10.4 from an anaconda environment.
The pylance version of my vscode is v2022.11.30.

When I highlight something while editing I get duplicated suggestions from highlighting and also in dropdown suggestions. (as stated in the pictures)

[image]

I tried an older version of pylance but didn't fix the issue. When I uninstall pylance it is not duplicated but I don't get any text highlighting.

If anyone else resolved this issue, please help me. It is a bit frustrating

Comment: Are you still experiencing this on recent versions of VS Code and PyLance?

Comment: pinging again. Are you still experiencing this? Could you please provide some code that minimally reproduces this issue along with tool version info? (a [mre])

Comment: possibly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74454797/vs-code-show-double-suggestion ?